# In the context of corporate profits, what does "back-half" mean?

Tags: terminology, equity, profitability, corporate-earnings, quarterly-report

Today, the following was reported:

> Clorox shares are trading lower after the company reported Q2 results. While the company beat estimates, it said it expects **back-half** sales to be about flat.

What does "back-half" mean in this context?

Answer (score 5):

The [back half](https://www.smartsalessolutions.com/smart-sales-blog-podcasts/make-back-half-2016-better-first/) of the year is the latter half, Q3 and Q4. In the Clorox case, it refers to a fiscal year.

Comment: Also written as H2.

Answer (score 4):

Since the company had reported results for the first half of the fiscal year (Q2 results), the rest of the year would be the "back half".  So "back half" sales would be sales in the next two quarters (Q3 and Q4).